# In excel shared workbook can you insert data and not replace on conflict?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have 2 users that asked for a shared excel workbook a while back.

Now after the holidays they complain that the workbook creates conflicts and that this issue never happened before. The file just inserted the rows like a database, one after the other.

I would like to know if there is a way to have multiple users insert data in excel by not overwriting data but just appending the rows in an excel file?

Any help would be appreciated.

Settings:

[image: Shared Workbook]

Comment: What do you mean "The file just inserted the rows like a database"? Are they both working in the file at the same time? Are they both using the same version of Excel (you tagged two versions)?

Comment: CharlieRB: thx for commenting. Yes they are using the same file at the same time. My apologies they both use 2007.

Comment: Consider a row of cells as a entry, and they both want to enter multiple entries, and don't care too much about the exact position their entries go. So they both type in cell A15 but instead of giving conflict on saving, they want one person's entry to go to A16.

Comment: What are the settings under the `Review Tab > Changes > Share Workbook`? If "*Allow changes by more than one user at the same time. This also allows workbook merging*" is not checked, then the workbook is not properly shared. Also what are the settings on the `Advanced` tab of the `Share workbook` window?

Comment: As you can see, excel assumes conflict resolution should be rewriting a cell. I would like to know if there is a way to shift rows down and insert conflicted data so both info stays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If sharing is turned on, it should be merging the data. Unfortunately, Excel's shared workbook feature is not a reliable tool. If the data is critical, you may want to consider not sharing and the users can only add their data one at a time. OR consider using a program, like Access, which is made for data sharing.